# Configure NFS server to accept connections from unpriviledged ports

Tags: filesystems, nfs, non-root-user

I'm working on custom-made NFS client and would like for the purpose of testing to allow connecting to my server from the ports that don't require elevated privileges. I'm sure there was a way of doing it, but can neither remember nor find it on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify the OS of the server, nor the server code.  If it's the standard Linux client then you specify "insecure" as part of the export
eg

```
/directory server(rw,no_root_squash,async,insecure)
```

Comment: It's the same NFS server that comes with Linux kernels, I don't think there were significant API changes in it in the past few decades. I'm not at my office right now and cannot test it, but I'm almost sure that's it.